# Projectile gets stuck at character's position (Unity2d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy sprite that is shooting out horizontal projectiles.  My only problem is that after the enemy shoots their projectile, it travels up until the position along x wherever my character is currently standing.

Let's say my enemy is on a platform above me and I'm standing -100f along the x-axis away from the enemy.  The enemy shoots their projectile, it travels for -100f along x and then gets stuck ("hovers") directly above my character sprite's head.

My code for the projectile is below (I've omitted extraneous variables that aren't affecting the motion of the projectile for simplicity's sake):

```
[SerializeField] GameObject player;  // Gets player's current position

private Transform transform;
private Vector2 projectilePosition;

void Update(){
     projectilePosition = transform.position;

     if (player.transform.position.x < transform.position.x) // if my player sprite is standing to the left of my projectile generator
     {
         projectilePosition += new Vector2(10f, 0);  // projectile flies from left to right
         transform.position = projectilePosition;
     }

    else if (player.transform.position.x > transform.position.x) // if my player sprite is standing to the right of my projectile generator
     {
         projectilePosition -= new Vector2(10f, 0);  // projectile flies from right to left
         transform.position = projectilePosition;
     }

}
```

Comment: And what do you want your projectile to do?

Comment: For it to travel along the x-axis up to a despawn point (I have another function that does this when x =  -10000f and x = 10000f called ResetProjectile())

Comment: I don't want my projectile getting stuck wherever my character is currently standing along the x-axis.

Comment: You want it to go away? Explode? Hit your character and travel to the ground with it?

Comment: I want it to PASS my character if it is not hitting my character (i.e. if my character is either above or below the projectile path)

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: if a rigidbody is attached to the projectile it can collide with a person's collider and cause the bullet to freeze

Comment: No rigidbody on the projectile, just a collider2d

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `player.transform.position.x` to determine the ordinate you want the projectile to travel towards, when the projectile is created, store `player.transform.position.x < transform.position.x` in a local variable in the projectile when you create it, so if the player was originally to the left of the spawn it will continue moving right, and vice versa

EXAMPLE:

In your projectile class, you'll need a boolean to store the direction, such as:
`movingLeft=False`

When you instantiate the projectile, you'll need to set whether it's moving left or right, so use

`movingLeft=player.transform.position.x < transform.position.x;`

then in your code replace

`player.transform.position.x < transform.position.x` with `movingLeft`

and replace `else if (player.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)` with `else`

Comment: What would be the data type for that variable?  Vector2?

Comment: It would be a bool.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  I'm just starting out with Unity2d, can you show an example?